# Android App Link failed with SingleHostAsyncVerifier return failed

Tags: android

I am trying to add app link in my app following [this](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations.html#web-assoc) instruction.
I've passed the test of the statement *assetlinks.json*.
I've also checked the log of *SingleHostAsyncVerifier*, but I couldn't figure out why it returned false.

```
2019-09-05 11:13:58.390 31360-31652/? 
I/SingleHostAsyncVerifier: Verification result: checking for a statement with source a: # bpkr@ad19471e
v: 21
, relation delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls, and target b <
  a: "com.jh.testproject"
  b: # bpkp@f2f5b17d
  v: 125
>
v: 127
 --> false.
```

Now, when I trying to open my app by link, the chooser still shows up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your test passed, check the headers whether it's accepting `json`. You should add header `Content-Type application-json` for `.well-known/assetlinks.json`

**Nginx configuration**

```
location = /.well-known/assetlinks.json {
  default_type 'application/json';
}
```

You can find more details about universal link configuration including *Amazon CloudFront* from here [Setting Up Universal Links](https://customer.io/docs/universal-links)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to know what do you mean by adding header for assetlinks.json? In my case, I use AWS S3 to deploy my website.

Comment: what is your web server Apache or Nginx?

Comment: Thanks for your info. I am using Amazon S3 to deploy my static website. But after I tried the steps from your link, it still didn't work. 
Finally, it worked after I build the apk with release variant.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Chathura Wijesinghe.

In case you are using Apache, here is the configuration to set the header **content-type** to **application/json**.

##### Apache 2.4.51 configuration

Create a file at /.well-known/.htaccess :

```
# BEGIN SET ASSETLINKS HEADER
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set content-type "application/json"
</IfModule>
# END SET ASSETLINKS HEADER
```